# Error on fetching weather data from WeatherAPI

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm using WeatherAPI to fetch current weather and decode it from JSON to human-readable format on apps using Flutter app. However, the app throws an error even though VSCode shows no error

Here's my Dart snippet for API calls:

```
`class CallToApi {
  Future<WeatherModel> callWeatherAPi(bool current, String cityName) async {
    try {
      Position currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition();

      if (current) {
        List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
            currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);

        Placemark place = placemarks[0];
        cityName = place.locality!;
      }

      var url = Uri.https('api.weatherapi.com', '/v1/current.json',
          {"key": apiKey, 'q': "Bekasi"});
      final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      log(response.body.toString());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);
        return WeatherModel.fromMap(decodedJson);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
    }
  }
`
```

And here's my JSON decoding snippet:

```
`class WeatherModel {
  final String temp;
  final String city;
  final String desc;

  WeatherModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : temp = json['temp_c'].toString(),
        city = json['name'],
        desc = json['condition:text'];
}`
```

When launched, it should shows current weather at Bekasi. However, when we launch it, it shows "Exception: Failed to load weather data" instead.

Any solution?

Comment: Dont show your exception, but print or throw the exception which is provided by the catch block.

Comment: Because by that you will get to know which part of the code is giving you the error

Comment: Can you print _response.statusCode_ and _response.body_ and show output ?

Comment: @PriyanshuPaliwal flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method placemarkFromCoordinates on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding)

Comment: @PriyanshuPaliwal, and when i compile it as an Android app, it shows "type 'Null' is not subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: @bélinda.freitas main:stdout> flutter: (weather JSON query, too long)
main:stdout> flutter: 200

Comment: @DedySimamora check line `json['condition:text']`, I'm pretty sure the key is not like that, so the value return _null_ wich is not a _String_. And check the key on the line `json['temp_c'].toString()` too.